# how to make fancyhdr headers positioning to not depend of size of ToC in two-sided document

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, fancyhdr

Consider this test case:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin={350pt, 350pt}]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}\author{}\date{}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{styletoc}{
    \fancyhead[RE]{Project Name}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
}
\fancypagestyle{stylemain}{
    \fancyhead[RE]{Project Name}
    \fancyhead[LO]{Chapter \nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

this page intentionally left blank
\newpage

\pagestyle{styletoc}
\tableofcontents
\newpage


\pagestyle{stylemain}
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\end{document}
```

According to `stylemain` page style definition, headers of such pages expected to contain [*chapter name* left, *page number* right] on odd pages, and [*page number* left, *project name* right] on even.

Unfortunately `stylemain` is used after ToC, which size varies of number of sections in document. So everything fine if number of pages of ToC is even, and became a mess, if odd (remove at least a single `\section{Test}\newpage` line from the testcase to reveal the issue).

What is a common rule in prepress for such cases? Like to add a blank page after ToC, if number of its pages is odd, or something.
And how to do that automatically by TeX, when size of ToC changes often.

Comment: Replace `\newpage` by `\cleardoublepage` after the ToC to let the next page be even. I don't know if this is what you're after?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I'm not familiar with the prepress rules, and offered to add blank page as a sample. The opened question, what is a rule for such cases, when document is printed as a book. After then it's possible to decide, whether `\cleardoublepage` can be considered as workaround or solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think, it is quite common to let chapter titles start on even pages. Not only after the ToC. I can only speak for myself, but I think it is good practice.

Comment: @JasperHabicht after some digging it turned out, that in such cases a blank page should be used after ToC, but not before Appendices. so `\cleardoublepage` is a solution of this issue. although a page should be completely blank, so in case of `fancyhdr` need few improvements, described in *Those blank pages* chapter of its documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\newpage` that follows `\tableofcontents` with `\cleardoublepage`. This way, a blank page will automatically be added if the table of contents has an odd number of pages, but not if it has an even number of pages.

In the following example, you will see that the page with the first section appears on the fifth page of the pdf, and it remains on the same page if you remove at least one `\section{Test}\newpage`.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin={350pt, 350pt}]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titling}
\title{Title}\author{}\date{}
\usepackage[title, titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{styletoc}{
    \fancyhead[RE]{Project Name}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
}
\fancypagestyle{stylemain}{
    \fancyhead[RE]{Project Name}
    \fancyhead[LO]{Chapter \nouppercase\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

this page intentionally left blank
\newpage

\pagestyle{styletoc}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage


\pagestyle{stylemain}
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\section{Test}\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is a solution, thank you